# IOS realease ITMS-90117: Missing routing app coverage file

Tags: ios, geojson

My IOS app is using the map function for showing route and following is the map related configuration from info.plist

```
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>MKDirectionsRequest</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Default</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>com.apple.maps.directionsrequest</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>MKDirectionsApplicationSupportedModes</key>
<array>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeBike</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeBus</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModeCar</string>
    <string>MKDirectionsModePedestrian</string>
</array>
```

The app is only focusing on sweden, and following is the "sweden.geojson" file. Where coordinates start with longitude then latitude, with three brackets to close a polygon. Last coordinate is same as the first one.

```
{
  "type": "MultiPolygon",
  "coordinates": [
    [[[9.755,54.977],[24.960,54.977],[24.960,69.565],[9.755,69.565],[9.755,54.977]]]
  ]
}
```

The initial **json** format validation passes, so I can do the submit, but then I got the emails with error: **invalid binary, IOS realease ITMS-90117: Missing routing app coverage file**. I even tried the sample json file from [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/ProvidingDirections/ProvidingDirections.html) but it is same error. Been on apple developer forum searching, but it is only problem posting, and no one posts any solution. Help appreciated...

Comment: We have absolutely the same issue, and unfortunelty, we didn't find solution yet

Comment: Apple tech team is aware of the problem now, fix will be applied soon.

Comment: I have the same problem. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not help you as I don't know the purpose of your app, but I had the same problem and and have found a solution that works for me.

I use MapKit to provide directions inside the app, but it isn't a directions app.

The solution was to turn off Map from the app capabilities (on the Signing and Capabilities tab). This setting indicates that the app works as a general purpose directions app.

I'm theorizing (but don't know for sure) that the reason the binary was invalid before I turned off the Map capability was that you can't have the capability enabled without providing a way to start the app with a location.